# Basis and subbasis of the standard topology

Tags: general-topology

Now given $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ I want to show that

a) The collection of all open intervalls $\{ (a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}: -\infty\leq a < b \leq \infty \}$ is a basis.

a) The collection of all half-infinite open intervalls $\{ (-\infty,a): a\in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{ (a,\infty): a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a subbasis but not a base.

*My idea*

a) Now let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be an open set. Then for every $x\in U$ there exists $\epsilon $ so that the open ball $B_\epsilon(x)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}: d(x,y)<\epsilon \} \subset U$. Now
$$
B_\epsilon(x)=\{y\in \mathbb{R}: d(x,y)<\epsilon \} = \{y\in \mathbb{R}: |x-y|<\epsilon \} = \{y\in \mathbb{R}: x-\epsilon < y < x+\epsilon \} = (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)
$$
So for all $x\in U$ there is an open intervall $I$ such that $x\in I \subset U$. Now I thought that one could then maybe write
$$
U=\bigcup_{x_i\in U} x_i \subset \bigcup_{x_i\in U} B_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)  \subset U
$$
so
$$
U=\bigcup_{x_i\in U} B_{\epsilon_i}(x_i)=\bigcup_{x_i\in U} (x_i-\epsilon_i,x_i+\epsilon_i)
$$
and $(x_i-\epsilon_i,x_i+\epsilon_i)\in \{ (a,b)\subset\mathbb{R}: -\infty\leq a < b \leq \infty \}$.

b) Now here I don't really know. I don't know how to show it is a subbasis or why not a basis. Isn't for $a<b$ that
$$
\{\{ (-\infty,a): a\in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{ (a,\infty): a\in \mathbb{R}\}\} \bigcap\{\{ (-\infty,b): b\in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{ (b,\infty): b\in \mathbb{R}\}\} = \\(-\infty,a) \bigcup  (a,b) \bigcup (b,\infty)
$$
but how can the union of these intersections be an open intervall/open set in $\mathbb{R}$? Also how do I show that it is not a basis? I think I might have to show that Unions of the subbase cannot form an open open intervall, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, if $a<b$, then $(-\infty,b)\cap(a,\infty)=(a,b)$. So, it follows from a) that the given set is a subbasis of the standard topology on $\Bbb R$.

But it's not a base: $0\in(-\infty,1)\cap(-1,\infty)$, but there is not interval of the form $(-\infty,a)$ or of the form $(a,\infty)$ to which $0$ belongs and which is a subset of $(-\infty,1)\cap(-1,\infty)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.